# Nullpointer exception on jersey put/post

Tags: heroku, jersey

i'm trying to do a put or post method on a jersey project hosted in heroku. Im getting this error trying to do a put. I'm getting the same error doing a post.

2015-05-20T21:30:29.145683+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.NullPointerException
2015-05-20T21:30:29.146362+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.wings.wingcore.JerseyCreates.register(JerseyCreates.java:49)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.146503+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.146782+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.147313+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.160539+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.148228+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:164)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.149055+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.160207+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.160210+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:269)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.160211+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.160804+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.160213+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.160544+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.146168+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.wings.wingcore.utils.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:85)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.150841+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.151920+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.152067+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.147166+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.150836+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.151625+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.152241+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:519)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.147721+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.152384+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.148645+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:181)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.150002+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.150006+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.151154+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.151476+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.149323+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:101)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.151772+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.150004+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.150995+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.152529+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.150053+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:305)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.150168+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.151314+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.150504+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.152675+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.152851+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1097)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.153416+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.150671+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.153001+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:446)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.159652+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.153412+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
2015-05-20T21:30:29.153414+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1031)

My put/post method:

```
@Path("addedit")
public class JerseyCreates {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();



    @PUT
    @Path("/register")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String register(String juserlogin) throws Exception {

        JUserLogin ju;
        String msg = "error";

            try{
                ju = gson.fromJson(juserlogin, JUserLogin.class);
                UserController.createUser(ju);
                msg = "done";
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return  msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: which one is line 49 in which the NPE happens?

Comment: ahg sorry, this line: UserController.createUser(ju); the problem is i'm getting a null json i think, but i dont know why

Comment: So does it happen within `UserController.createUser(ju);`? Then please show the code within the createUser method. UserController is a class and cannot be null, right?

Comment: CreateUser is a class with static methods for manage a database with hibernate. createUser calls a service class which calls the dao methods. So ju is the "user" object which i want  save in my database

Comment: as i said: "Then please show the code within the createUser method." - BTW. have you checked if `ju == null`?

Comment: public class UserController {

static UserServiceImpl uservice = context.getBean("userService",
   UserServiceImpl.class);
   
public static void createUser(JUserLogin juser) {
  User user = new User(0, juser.getName(), juser.getPassword(),
    "shouter_logo", juser.getEmail());
  uservice.save(user);
 }

}

Comment: Either juser is null (Probably the `ju` var you passed into the method), or uservice is null - which would be a misconfiguration. Please do some debugging by yourself.

Comment: i will write a response tomorrow. Thanks for the support!